# Using term space of column formulate the following statements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$,$ x\in \mathbb R^n$, and $b\in \mathbb R^m$. Using term column space of matrix, formulate a necessary and sufficient condition:

a)System $Ax=b$ have a solution

If $b \in L(A_{\cdot 1},A_{\cdot2},\cdots , A_{\cdot n})$

b)System $Ax=b$ have unique solution

If matrix $A$ have n linear independent column

c)System $Ax=b$ have solution $\forall  b \in \mathbb R^m$

If matrix $A$ have $m$ linear independent column

d)System $Ax=b$ have unique solution for every $b\in \mathbb R^m$

the same as for $c)$

I do not know what is different in this question, ok for a I know that if $rankA<n$ then it does not mean that have solution for every b, but if $rankA=n$ it have solution for every b, so that mean that have pivot in every row, but other question look the same, can you help me if I miss something.

Comment: An arbitrary $b$ is in $\Bbb{R}^m$, so you need $m$ linearly independent columns of $A$ to represent it.  Since column rank is the same as row rank (proved by induction), this can be written concisely as $\mathop{rank}(A) = m$.

Comment: you think that for c I need to write m linear independent column?

Comment: Yes.  To exaggerate this, think of $(m,n) = (2018,1)$